# sed works on commandline but not in script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, sed

Why does this work when I type it direct on the commandline:

```
oldversion=12345
newversion=67890
sed -i "s/${oldversion}/${newversion}/g" "/home/user/MyDir_${newversion}/MyDir_${newversion}.reg"
```

But when I put it in a script it doesn't:

```
#!/bin/bash
oldversion=12345
newversion=67890
sed -i "s/${oldversion}/${newversion}/g" "/home/user/MyDir_${newversion}/MyDir_${newversion}.reg"
```

It is executed as `./myscript.sh`

It generates the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'

Comment: OP, maybe it's time to fix your setup... it's [clearly of problem of locale/encoding.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296847)

Comment: I just had to run `export LANG=C` because of a problem renaming a directory. Do I need to reset it to something different every time I do something?

Comment: I know that you had to do that (if you check the link in my comment...) hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character 16 in the sed script does not exist.  This is the `"` character that sed is complaining about, and that means that your editor or input method replaced it with some non-ASCII rendition of `"`.  My guess would be either `“` or `”` or `¨`.

Use `file` on your file in order to get some guess on the encoding.  It should be "ASCII".  Anything else hints to the file containing stuff you did not intend to be there.

Comment: OK cheers, that makes sense. The file is an export of some registry settings from WINE, so the encoding is probably not ASCII.

Comment: Thank you! I just wasted a few hours of my life troubleshooting a `sed` command in a shell script that just wasn't doing anything, nor erroring out. Saw your answer and bingo! `file` reported `Bourne-Again shell script executable (binary data)`. Sure enough, for some reason there was a sneaky `DLE` char in the regex string ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯